# Чтение файла не до конца

Tags: c++, c, файлы, ввод

у меня есть условный torrent файл, который мне требуется прочитать. При чтении программа читает лишь 828 символов из 11863. Для чтения я использую данный код:

```
void _readf(char * _fname)
{
    char c;
    FILE * fp= fopen(_fname, "r");
    if(fp)
    {   
        int i = 0;
        while((c=getc(fp))!= EOF)
        {
            _finfo[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        _flen = i + 1;
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Readed %d", _flen);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправьте для начала две строки:

```
int c;
FILE * fp= fopen(_fname, "rb");
```

Так не завершит чтение ни считанный символ с кодом -1, ни с кодом 26, он же `Ctrl-Z` (если это в Windows).